# MLE estimate for a complicated model

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization

I would like to find the MLE estimate for the following model.
I am given $x_i, t_i, \sigma_i, Z_i$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$. I am also given functions $f_j$ for $j = 1,\ldots, m$.

$$Z_i = \sum_{j = 1}^m c_j \cdot f_j(x_i, z_i) \cdot Y_{ij} + N(0, \sigma_i^2)$$
Where $Y_{ij} \sim N(0,1)$ and $<Y_{i_1j},Y_{i_2j}> = \exp(-\lambda_j|t_{i_1} - t_{i_2}|)$

I would like to find the parameters $c_j, \lambda_j$ that maximize the likelihood of getting the specified values $Z_i$.

I would like to find the closed form, but I couldn't.

Instead I tried numerically optimize. Let
$$\Sigma_{i_1, i_2} = \sum_j c_j^2 \cdot f_j(x_{i_1},t_{i_1}) \cdot f_j(x_{i_2},t_{i_2}) + \delta_{i_1,i_2}\sigma_{i_1}^2$$
Where $\delta_{i_1,i_2}$ is the Kronecker Delta function.
I wish to maximize the logpdf
$$f(\vec{c},\vec{\lambda}) = -1/2 \vec{z}^T\Sigma^{-1}\vec{z} - 1/2\log(det(2\pi\Sigma)) $$
Unfortunately standard optimizer from scipy was too slow for this. I would guess if I provide jacobian for $f$, it would be faster, but I don't know how to calculate that.

Please help me find a closed form solution or a faster way to find the parameters.

Comment: P.S. I didn't know what to call this model. I would appreciate if someone could improve the title of the question.

Comment: Welcome to the site! For nonlinear likelihoods with many continuous parameters, a gradient based approach is indeed the way to go. Luckily, we're past the point of having to calculate these gradients ourselves. I would try using Tensorflow or PyTorch's autodiff to calculate gradients, and start off by plugging it into a simple optimizer like gradient descent or Adam with fixed step size.